# Trim the paths from git diff result in Groovyscript

Tags: git, grails, groovy

I am trying to trim the paths from git diff result. Here is what I have tried :

```
def ti = "git -C C:\\PIE\\src\\repo diff --name-only".execute()
String directory =ti.text
File  file= new File(directory)

 def newlines = []
    file.toString().eachLine {String line ->
    if(line.contains("src")){

        line = line.replace("/src","")
    }
    newlines<<line

    }
    println newlines
```

The output from gif diff for example is like :

```
a/b/c/src/ping.java
d/e/f/src/vim.java
g/h/j/src/key.java
```

I would like to trim each line in the file currentDir as :

```
a/b/c
d/e/f
g/h/j
```

Comment: You have edited your question to ask an entirely different question that you originally asked.  This is very confusing to anyone who comes across this later.  Please ask new questions as new questions instead of repurposing old ones.

Comment: yeah will keep that in mind. I was a bit confused about it. My bad

Comment: Creating a File with the `git diff` will bug if you have more than one file diff. If you don't use the file instance for something else, just do `ti.text.eachLine {}`. You can than create a File instance if required. Or even a groovier approach: `ti.text.readLines().grep { it.contains("src") }.collect { it = it.replaceAll("/src", "") }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the `/src` portion and all that follows it, you could do this:

```
line = line.replaceAll("/src.*","")
```

instead of what you have:

```
line = line.replace("/src","")
```